# HAProxy will only log start up message

Tags: logging, tcp, haproxy, rsyslog

I'm trying to get HAProxy to log tcp traffic I've been doing to no success. Here are my confs:

/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

```
global
    log /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log local0 debug
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log local4 debug
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 10000
    timeout server 10000

listen sco 0.0.0.0:80
    log /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log local4 debug
    mode tcp
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    balance roundrobin

cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server test11 172.21.0.3:8888 check cookie test11
    server test12 172.21.0.2:8888 check cookie test12
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/49-haproxy.conf

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514

local0.* -/var/log/haproxy/haproxy_0.log
local4.* -/var/log/haproxy/haproxy_4.log
if ($programname == 'haproxy') then -/var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log
& ~
```

The output I get is just the proxy start up line.

/var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log

```
Mar 31 18:23:19 74f09d6f9f70 haproxy[27]: Proxy sco started.
```

/var/log/haproxy/haproxy_4.log

```
Mar 31 18:23:19 74f09d6f9f70 haproxy[27]: Proxy sco started.
```

I generated some traffic. HAProxy redirects it correctly but won't log anything. I wonder what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can only log to a syslog server not to a file.

Review the documentation at:  http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#8

Comment: I configured rsyslog to write in that file, not haproxy

Answer (score 0):

Since you have

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514
```

that means rsyslog is listening on 127.0.0.1:514 for log messages (otherwise it would only read the unix socket `/var/lib/haproxy/dev/log`), so you can change your config to

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log 127.0.0.1 local4 debug
```

and it should work.  The caveat is that using 127.0.0.1 is slower than the unix socket dev/log.  How to get it to work with dev/log is something I can't answer yet, but I hope this clarifies what's going on.